# How to calculate a running date using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

I have a list of customers who received an email on different dates. Based on the day the email was sent, I want to calculate the date a year back (i.e. if the email was sent 2019-07-01, I need to extract 2018-07-01 for that particular customer) and then I need this new (old) date as a value in my table. How can I best do this using postgreSQL?

It seems like I figured it out with help from you. My code

```
     select cast(cdi_senton as date) as senton
     , senton - interval '365 day' as senton_lastyear
```

Comment: Use the dateadd function, eg select DateAdd(year, -1, GetDate())

Answer (score 0):

For TSQl (Sql Server)Use the dateadd function, eg

```
select DateAdd(year, -1, GetDate())
```

The will subtract a year from today, substitute your own date for GetDate()

If using mySql, use Date_add (google it for the syntax)

If Oracle, DateAdd also exists, just check the arguments

If something else, I got nuthin.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use postgreSQL. It seems that GetDate doesn't exists?

"ERROR:  function getdate(date) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts."

Comment: See the previous answer for postgres solution

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to answer fully because you didn't tell us which database product you're using, but it's not a huge problem - just google for `<name of your db> date sub`  to get the syntax relevant to your db for doing date math, then slot it into a query like this:

```
UPDATE customer SET email_date = <the function you googled, to subtract one year>
```

Replace `email_date` with the actual name of your table column

Examples:

#### SQL server:

```
UPDATE customer SET email_date = DATEADD(year, -1, email_date)
```

#### Oracle:

```
UPDATE customer SET email_date = ADD_MONTHS(email_date, -12)
```

#### MySQL:

```
UPDATE customer SET email_date = DATE_SUB(email_date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

#### PostgreSQL

*credits and thanks to a_horse_with_no_name*

```
UPDATE customer SET email_date = email_date - interval '1' year;
```

Bear in mind that even if you can only find examples that add a date, you can pass a minus number to it to go back in time

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm sorry that I forgot to mention that I use postgreSQL. I would like to calcualte and extract the date in a select-statement (forgot to write that too..).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply subtract [an interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html):

```
select cast(cdi_senton as date) as senton, 
       cdi_senton - interval '1 year' as senton_last_year
from the_table 
...;
```

This assumes that `cdi_senton` is defined as `date` or `timestamp`

Online example: https://rextester.com/MPJM45737

Comment: Thank you. It worked worked when I used 365 days. I got an error when I tried to use 1 year.

Comment: @Cathrine: then you are not using Postgres or you did not write it the correct way.